# How to turn off ECHO in a script that is used in both CMD and BASH

Tags: bash, cmd

We have a script that is used on both Windows and Linux as an easy entry point to building our repository. For example, this script uses `: #` as a way to make a comment that is ignored on both CMD and Bash.

```
: # This script can be used from both CMD and Bash.

python scripts/build.py && python scripts/test.py
```

It does the job, but I don't like how on Windows it prints out the command before running it because echo is on. If I add `@ECHO OFF` I get an error in Bash. Bash defaults to echo being off.

I'm looking for a clever way to turn off echo in CMD without causing a problem in Bash.

Comment: Use PowerShell on both Linux and Windows. https://github.com/powershell/powershell

Comment: [PolyShell](https://github.com/llamasoft/polyshell) (a bash/batch/PowerShell polyglot script outline) has some useful tricks you might be able to adapt to get parts of the script to run in one interpreter but not the other. It looks to me like the opening `echo ...` command could be modified to make the following section run in batch but not bash, but *not* exit at the end. But I don't have a batch runner handy to test with...

Answer (score 0):

How is this script in your code block invoked? By doubleclicking some file? Or by executing it via a command line?

I am thinking about something like this:
If you invoke another batch script with an `@echo off` inside and then call your script within the same cmd session, the "echo off mode" should be still in place. Under Linux just leave out the call to "echooff.bat".
But essentially, this is equivalent to have two start script files, one for Windows, one for Linux.

Or if you can relinquish the output to console entirely, you could just redirect to `> nul` or some `> myoutputfile.txt`, which should work on both platforms the same way (I can give no guarantee, cannot test it).
You could try to incorporate a `tail -f myoutputfile.txt`, if showing the output live is valuable. Under Windows this might need a `tail` present in the PATH, e.g. from Cygwin or a Windows port of `tail`. Or use some text editor to show the file on both platforms. I think Notepad++, Atom and Emacs are cross platform for example.